# How to get warnings from schema aware xslt using Saxon API

Tags: saxon

I have some c# prototype code that compiles and then executes an XSLT.

```
        var samplesDir = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        // Create a Processor instance.
        Processor processor = new Processor(true);


        var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
        try
        {
            // Create a transformer for the stylesheet.
            Xslt30Transformer transformer = compiler.Compile(new Uri(samplesDir, "po.xsl")).Load30();
            // Create a serializer, with output to the standard output stream
            Serializer serializer = processor.NewSerializer();
            serializer.SetOutputWriter(Console.Out);

            // Transform the source XML and serialize the result document
            transformer.SchemaValidationMode = SchemaValidationMode.Strict;
            transformer.ApplyTemplates(File.OpenRead("po.xml"), serializer);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.WriteLine("Schema compilation failed with " + compiler.ErrorList.Count + " errors");
            foreach (StaticError error in compiler.ErrorList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("At line " + error.LineNumber + ": " + error.Message);
            }
        }
```

and an XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    
    <xsl:import-schema schema-location="file:///C:/Users/m_r_n/source/repos/SaxonEEExample/ValidateXslt/po1.xsd" />

    <xsl:template match="schema-element(PurchaseOrder)">
      <xsl:for-each select="item">
          <xsl:value-of select="@id" />: <xsl:value-of select="title" />
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:message terminate="yes">Source document is not a purchase order
        </xsl:message>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I change the match to

```
<xsl:template match="schema-element(PurchaseOrder1)">
```

then this will correctly report an error

```
  At line 8: There is no declaration for element <PurchaseOrder1> in an imported schema
```

Brilliant.

If I change that back and amend the for-each line to

```
  <xsl:for-each select="item1">
```

then oxygen editor (using Saxon EE), correctly reports a warning for this line

```
The complex type of element PurchaseOrder does not allow a child element named item1
```

yet my C# code, will happily compile it and execute it (outputting an empty string).

How do I get the saxon compiler to report warnings?
What is Oxygen doing that my code doesnt do?

Answer (score 0):

Saxon is probably outputting the warning to the console, and you're not seeing what's on the console.

Try capturing the errors from the compiler by setting the `ErrorList` or `ErrorReporter` property (depending on which release you're using) of the `XsltCompiler`.

Comment: I do see the errors when I get an error, if I stop the debugger after the compile then I don't see anything in compiler.ErrorList, but let me follow your instructions and see what happens

Comment: bingo, its there....I didnt need to set the Errorlist, it was just not appearing at the point I was expecting.

Comment: ah...its there AFTER I "ApplyTemplates()", is there a way for it to be detected before actually executing the XSLT? I'm trying to statically validate a set of XSLTs without executing them (I may have no data to execute against).

Comment: Then you want to disable JIT compilation. Set the `FastCompliation` property (sic) on the `XsltCompiler` to false.

Comment: Actually, looking at the code, I'm not sure this is going to work. See https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4816.

Comment: ah ok...how does Oxygen do it? I can confirm that FastCompliation is already false.

Comment: Oxygen uses the Java API, which has a method `XsltCompiler.setJustInTimeCompilation(false)`, for some reason that hasn't been exposed in the .NET API. As a workaround, you can dive down into the innards using XsltCompiler.GetUnderlyingCompilerInfo(), and call `setJustInTimeCompilation(config.isJITEnabled())` on the returned CompilerInfo object.

Comment: what about..            processor.SetProperty("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/optimizationLevel", "-j"); that seems to work

Comment: compiler.GetUnderlyingCompilerInfo().setJustInTimeCompilation(false);
does work, you have to start addding a few more references from the bin directory, but to be fair its better than the magic "-j" option

Comment: I'll post the solution

Answer (score 0):

This is largely a summary of the result of conversation with Michael Kay.

The issue seems to be that JIT is set to true by default, and JIT means that warnings are evaluated, I assume, lazily, which can be on execution.

You can override this either by setting the property on the processor using the magic "-j" option, then I assume all created compilers will not lazily evaluate warnigns, or, actually for me preferably, go into the underlying compiler info and set it to off (this requires adding in a few more references to your app, but the compiler will tell you what you need to do).

```
        var samplesDir = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        // Create a Processor instance.
        Processor processor = new Processor(true);

        var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
        // option 1 - set the JIT flag to false in the underlying compiler info
        compiler.GetUnderlyingCompilerInfo().setJustInTimeCompilation(false);
        // option 2 - set JIT optimization off
        //processor.SetProperty("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/optimizationLevel", "-j");
        try
        {
            Xslt30Transformer transformer = compiler.Compile(new Uri(samplesDir, "po.xsl")).Load30();
            // Create a serializer, with output to the standard output stream
            Serializer serializer = processor.NewSerializer();
            serializer.SetOutputWriter(Console.Out);

            // Transform the source XML and serialize the result document
            transformer.SchemaValidationMode = SchemaValidationMode.Strict;
            transformer.ApplyTemplates(File.OpenRead("po.xml"), serializer);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.WriteLine("Schema compilation failed with " + compiler.ErrorList.Count + " errors");
            foreach (StaticError error in compiler.ErrorList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("At line " + error.LineNumber + ": " + error.Message);
            }
        }
```